# How to align multiple elements below each other?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am having difficulty in aligning Swing elements flow below each other. Using `GridLayout` does not help me because it divides screen to rows which have equal sizes.  I need to put one component to each row and the next component should be in very bottom of the last component.

[image]

Mi problem is that if the choices of the question are more than one line, this layout squeeze them to the rows and there is a huge gap between picture and question "3+3?"

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the current UI you have and explain the problem?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nGrlF.png

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) To compact a single column `GridLayout` down to the minimum it needs at the top or bottom of a container, put the panel with grid layout into the `PAGE_START` or `PAGE_END` constraint of a `BorderLayout` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GridBagLayout` for this. It is very easy to use. Here is a sample implementation.

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel image = new JLabel();
        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.png")));

        JLabel question = new JLabel("3 + 3 = ?");

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("5");
        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("3");
        JRadioButton rb3 = new JRadioButton("6");
        JRadioButton rb4 = new JRadioButton("9");
        JRadioButton rb5 = new JRadioButton("23");

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;//set the x location of the grid for the next component
        c.gridy = 0;//set the y location of the grid for the next component
        panel.add(image,c);

        c.gridy = 1;//change the y location
        c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;//left align components after this point
        panel.add(question,c);

        c.gridy = 2;//change the y location
        panel.add(rb1,c);

        c.gridy = 3;//change the y location
        panel.add(rb2,c);

        c.gridy = 4;//change the y location
        panel.add(rb3,c);

        c.gridy = 5;//change the y location
        panel.add(rb4,c);

        c.gridy =6;//change the y location
        panel.add(rb5,c);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

References: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: It works but problem it always centers the componets after the picture.Components after picture should be left alligned.I could not do that

Comment: `c.anchor` should be set to align.

Comment: 'c.achor' does not work.If you execute your code, when you resize you frame , this layout puts components to the center of the frame.

Comment: Add `c.weightx = 1;` after the `GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();` line. Then the `RadioButton`s will stick to the left side of the frame.

Comment: PS: I forgot to tell you in the last comment. `c.anchor` only align the element within the `panel`.If you want the align the `RadioButton`s within the `frame`, then you have to resize the `panel` when the frame is resizing like I did in the last comment or add the `image`, `RadioButton`s separately to the `frame` after setting the `frame`'s layout to `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of possible solutions, probably the most useful however is `GridBagLayout`, while complex, it is very flexible.

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Cool");
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48f));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(label, gbc);
            add(new JLabel("3+5="), gbc);
            add(new JCheckBox("5"), gbc);
            add(new JCheckBox("3"), gbc);
            add(new JCheckBox("6"), gbc);
            add(new JCheckBox("9"), gbc);
            add(new JCheckBox("23"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

You could even use an `anchor` to move the components to different positions within there cells...

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

[image: Anchor]

These can, obviously, be applied to individual components as well, so each component can have it's own set of constraints

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: It would also be useful if the correct answer were one of the choices.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. I've used the same approach in my application, where I needed to display my elements inside the ```JPanel``` in the block. Maybe just one question : I it ok, to define different ```GridBagConstraints``` for each element, or I'll be just fine with one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @rchrd Depends on your needs. `GridBagLayout` makes a copy of the constraints itself for each component